# Differentiation under the integral sign - Proof

Tags: calculus

Calculate the derivative of $I(x)$:
$$
I(x)=\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(x,s)ds.
$$
The solution should be:
$$
I'(x)=h(x,g(x))g'(x)-h(x,f(x))f'(x)+\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\frac{\partial h(x,s)}{\partial x}ds.
$$ 
I've tried many different ways to solve this (using the definition of partial derivatives, the same problem but with one variable...) but I don't seem to get to the correct answer, it just gets messy. How do I go along to solve this? Is the solution even correct?

Thanks

Comment: If regularity allows, a proof of this can be found in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 1):

Call the integral $I(x)=F(x,f(x),g(x))$. Now use *partial* derivatives to calculate $\frac{dI}{dx}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

You can use Fundamental Theorem of calculus to evaluate the partials.